# How can I add required attribute to the fileds in react js?

Tags: reactjs, validation

In the code I want to have a required attribute to make the field mandatory . But its not working.. Any simple way in react for this validation?

```
<label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" className="form-control"
id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required/>
```

Comment: Could you please add your component's code to your question?

Answer (score 5):

Try to add form and button tags:

```
<form onSubmit={handler}>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required />
  <button type="submit" />
</form
```

If this doesn't work, try replacing `required` with `required="required"`

Comment: then also im not getting

Comment: Sorry... These were all my ideas... So the only way is to check its value onChange, onBlur, on submission (part of all). Maybe take a look at something that I created long ago to use as a starting point that will hopefully save you time: https://github.com/rahamin1/reactstrap-form

Comment: how to write a nested if condition inside a function in react js ?

Comment: Not sure what you ask... Please elaborate on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is you can create `onblur`/`onchange` function for input tag and check in that function that string you have typed is empty or not. If it is empty you can assign a variable in state and then call `this.setState` function. Now make `<span>` tag below `<input>` tag and render your state variable in `<span>` tag.